# Can spring's oauth support be used to provide single sign on across platforms with multiple oauth providers?

Tags: spring, authentication, oauth, spring-security

I've seen some stuff in spring's oauth support that looks quite promising but I'm wondering how mature it is. I would like to provide single sign on for a web app for multiple oauth providers, and also authenticate native mobile rest api clients.

Are there many differences in implementations between various oauth providers or is the standard adhered to tightly?

Answer (score 1):

[Spring Social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social) might help you. Spring social will help you to sign in to your application through providers like Facebook and Twitter.

Most of the providers have OAuth 1.x or OAuth 2.x implementations. With spring social there is no much difference from our part for integrating OAuth 1 OR 2 provider sign in.

You can go for a Spring social implementation together with [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/reference.html) too